# Storing String from file in an ArrayList object?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Cities {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filename;
        System.out.println("Enter the file name : ");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        filename = kb.next();

        //Check if file exists 
          File f = new File(filename);

          if(f.exists()){

            //Read file
            File myFile = new File(filename);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

            //Create arraylist object
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            String cit;

            while(inputFile.hasNext()){
                cit = inputFile.toString();
                list.add(inputFile.toString());
            }
            System.out.println(list);  

          }else{
              System.out.println("File not found!");
          }   
    }   
}
```

I am trying to read a file and add the contents to an `arraylist` object (`.txt` file contains strings), but I am totally lost. Any advice?

Comment: I am a beginner so please go easy!

Comment: A ballpark estimation of the difference between Programmers.SE and StackOverflow is if you are in front of a whiteboard or an IDE when dealing with the problem.  If you are looking at a whiteboard (trying to figure out the algorithm, the design patterns, etc...) then its likely best on P.SE.  If it is in an IDE, its probably best on StackOverflow.  Your previous question was migrated (automatically moved) to SO and this one is on its way too (please don't repost).  For implementation questions (such as this), SO will likely give you an answer much faster than P.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the file one line by one line and store it to the list.

Here is the code you should replace your `while (inputFile.hasNext())`:

```
Scanner input = null;
try
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    input = new Scanner( new File("") );
    while ( input.hasNext() )
        list.add( input.nextLine() );
}
finally
{
    if ( input != null )
        input.close();
}
```

And you should close the `Scanner` after reading the file.

Comment: What about using while and if loops? I am unfamiliar with try-finally.

Comment: @user104827 `try ... finally ...` syntax here is used to close `Scanner` properly.

Comment: `while ( input.hasNext() )` loop each line in file, if you have to filter the input line, you can add `if` condition in the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7+, then you can use the [`Files#readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to do this task for you, instead of you writing a `for` or a `while` loop yourself to read the file line-by-line.

```
File f = new File(filename); // The file from which input is to be read.
ArrayList<String> list = null; // the list into which the lines are to be read
try {
    list = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error, do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one single line with Guava.

```
final List<String> lines = Files.readLines(new File("path"), Charsets.UTF8);
```

[http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines(java.io.File, java.nio.charset.Charset)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)